# padding-left 100% on element extends over parent left border

Tags: css, animation

I'd need to extend the padding-left or margin-left of a div to 100% for an animation, but the text in the div is then outside the parent box resp. outside its padding on the right side.

[image: padding-left:100%]

The div is within a bootstrap `<div class="row"><div class="col-mod-12">...</div></div>`, but has otherwise no special formatting.

Do you have a tip for me how I can push the element with the help of an animatable CSS property (text-align is not animatable) to the right, but within the parent container? I'd be grateful.

code (without browser pre-fix):

```
<style>
@keyframes slidein {
  0% { padding-left: 0; }
  100% { padding-left: 100%; } }

div.slideIn {
  animation: slidein 3s infinite alternate; }
</style>

<div class="slideIn">
Animate
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

Asking always helps to trigger thinking. It works as follows:

```
@keyframes slidein {
  0% { width: 0; }
  100% { width: 100%; } }

div.slideIn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  animation: slidein 3s infinite alternate; }
```

Sorry to bother. But MDN has an example with margin-left: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations